# How can I prevent my python list from converting bytes into integers automatically?

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I'm reading a sequence of bytes to a list in python so that I can use them later, however some of the bytes are in pairs which represent one value. For some reason when I extend my list using `list.extend(byte)`, it converts the bytes to integer values automatically, meaning that I can't get my two byte values back as they are now returned as two separate integers. E.g. my list is now 184 22 1 1.... instead of the appropriate hex values. How can I parse the bytes to a list while keeping them as bytes? Many thanks.

EDIT: I fixed the problem by initialising the list as a bytearray instead.

Comment: can you prepare a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 0):

Initialising the list as a bytearray fixed the problem